# Resolve maven dependencies from JFrog artifactory by configuration in pom.xml

Tags: maven, pom.xml, artifactory, jfrog-cli

I need to point Maven to JFrog artifactory ONLY to resolve dependencies and not to deploy. For this I'm not allowed to use settings.xml.

I found  artifactory-maven-plugin][1](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Maven+Artifactory+Plugin) but it show only how to deploy. The main issue that I need to set username/password to access JFrog and also setup Virtual Repos to resolve artifacts and plugins.

And thoughts how to this without settings.xml via pom.xml? Creds I can add to env variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `<repositories>` section to your POM. It will not override your `<distributionManagement>` (for deployment). Whether it will actually work depends on the mirror settings in the `settings.xml`.

Actually, I find it strange that you do not want to change the `settings.xml`. If you are not responsible for the `settings.xml`, you can talk to the relevant manager. You could also ask if the relevant repository is added to the company repository as proxy (if you have such a thing).

Comment: In repositories there is no possibility to add credentials. Without them maven couldn't reach JFrog. I need to do this, because I want to build jar on linux server, where I don't want to have setting.xml

Comment: Normally, every build server has a `settings.xml`. I see no reason why you should not put one on your linux server.

Comment: because it is CodePipeline and every project has its own. I want to add this configuration of <repositories> etc. into parent pom.xml and then use inheritance. If not then I need to download settings.xml to every code pipeline (to every linux server)

Comment: You also need to install Maven on every server. Copying the `settings.xml` is more or less part of your Maven installation process. If you use docker instead, you could just build a docker image that already contains the `settings.xml`.

Comment: If want a project specific `settings.xml`, though, you can just add it to the git repository and then reference it in the Maven build.